# Weird characters while merging text files

Tags: character-encoding

When i open the text file in windows the text looks fine.
But when i use text miler merger software then it shows some weird chinese characters for that files.

but i reads ok the files after.

how can i make all the files to same encoding so that they appear readable

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) and there is an option to change the encoding of one or many files.

Comment: Notepad++ is a really good suggestion for this - you can see the encoding of each file and easily change it.

Answer (score 1):

[iconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) will let you batch-convert the character set used by the files.